# AWS S3 sync between buckets overwriting newer destination files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

We have two s3 buckets, and we have a sync cron job that should copy bucket1 changes to bucket2.

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket1/images/ s3://bucket2/images/
```

When a new image is added to bucket1, it correctly gets copied over to bucket2.

However, if we upload a new version of that image to bucket2, when the sync job next runs it actually copies the older version from bucket1 over to bucket2, replacing the newer version we just put there.

This is part of a migration process, and in time the only place images will be uploaded to will be bucket2, but for the time being sometimes they may be uploaded to either, and we only want changes form bucket1 to be copied up to bucket2, NOT the other way round.

Why does the aws sync job seem to think that the file on bucket1 has changed? Does it not know that the file in bucket2 is newer, so it should be left alone?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command copies content from the Source location to the Destination location. It only copies files that have been added or changed since the last sync.

It is designed as a **one-way sync**, not a two-way sync. Your file is being overwritten because the file in the Source is not present in the Destination. This is **correct behavior**.

There is limited range to tweak these controls, such as (from the [sync command documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)):

> `--exact-timestamps` (boolean) When syncing from S3 to local, same-sized items will be ignored only when the timestamps match exactly. The default behavior is to **ignore same-sized items unless the local version is newer than the S3 version**.

However, there does not appear to be an option that stops overwriting of files merely because a file with the same name exists, or something with a preference to keep newer files.

If you want a two-way sync with more specific rules, you will need to code it yourself.

Comment: There is no flag that just compares the time and do not upload if the file has the same name and is newer? Doing the `aws s3 sync` in both ways works really fine for my situation, the only problem is this.

Comment: @SoonSantos Sorry, but your requirements are unclear. If a local and remote file is found with the same name, in what situation do you want the file copied?

Comment: If the local has the same file name as the remote, but the local file is older than the remote file, `aws s3 sync local remote` will replace the new remote file with the local, I would like it not to replace because the remote file is newer. On the other way, `aws s3 sync remote local` I would like it to replace. But as you said it is a one-way sync and I do not think this feature is possible.

Comment: I edited the comment, sorry for the mistype.

Comment: @SoonSantos The documentation says _"A local file will require uploading if the size of the local file is different than the size of the s3 object, the last modified time of the local file is **newer** than the last modified time of the s3 object, or the local file does not exist under the specified bucket and prefix."_ This seems to differ from what you are experiencing. If so, please create a new Question rather than asking this via a comment on an old Question.